# Xcode not able to find framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, frameworks

I have a project with Pods installed, apart from pods, I have a framework that has to be added. I added the framework in the project in

> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries

and also added

> framework search path as $(PROJECT_DIR)/MyFramework.framework.

I have copied the framework in the project directory. Still I am getting the error undeclared identifier. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: how do you import the framework header into your class ?

Comment: In the framework there is a header class which imports all the classes in the framework.. I am importing that header class in pch file..

Comment: do u use use framework option in podfile ?

Comment: The framework which I am using doesn't have cocoa pods support..

Comment: What is the language used by the framework and what is the language used to call it?

Comment: Did you add the header file to your project in the XCode environment?

Comment: @jvarela objective C

Comment: @dstudeba - Sorry, I didn't get you.. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to include your framework, you need to follow these steps, particularly if you are still using objective C and are not using modules:

1. Add your framework to your project by going to **Navigation Area -> Your Project -> Target -> General -> Embedded binaries** and then click on + sign and add your framework as a binary (I am assuming it is already in binary form).
2. If you have the source code of the framework and want to keep it always up to date, then add it as a target dependency in **Navigation Area -> Your Project -> Target -> Build Phases -> target dependencies**
3. [It is recommended](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html) that you create an umbrella header for your framework and then include it in your project as so `#import <Framework_name/Header_filename.h>`, particularly if you don't have access to its source code. However, if you do have access to the source code and have the headers of each particular file of the framework you can add those specific headers in your project and then import them in each file of your project using `#import "Header_Filename.h"`. You can even include them in a precompiled header so that they are imported by default and you can even omit the import directives or even the addition of a header search path.

Hope this helps.